# FusedLocationProviderClient taking 5sec for update, I need it per second

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get location update in my app. I am creating `LocationRequest` with `interval` of `1 sec` and `maxInterval` of `0.5 sec` but location update is taking average of `6 sec`.

I am testing this on Nexus 5, Nexus 5x and Moto G (2nd Gen) devices.

I didn't found any limit about `interval` or `maxInterval` in Documentation, So i am assuming it should give update in `1 sec` atleast.

Also, I am requesting location from a `Foreground Services`.

Please Suggest how to get update location update each second or is there any limitation mentioned in Documentation.

Comment: If you are not doing it in the background you can use the location callback: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. @Randheer Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

By looking at the reference by Android at: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html

**setInterval(long)** means - set the interval in which you want to get locations. **setFastestInterval(long)** means - if a location is available sooner you can get it (i.e. another app is using the location services).

For example, you start your application and register it via setInterval(60*1000), that means that you'll get updates every 60 seconds.
Now you call setFastestInterval(10*1000). If you are the only app which use the location services you will continue to receive updates every 60 seconds. If another app is using the location services with a higher rate of updates, you will get more location updates.

Note: Basically In your mobile,having some application for requesting location updates in background..that time you cannot get location updates as you set Interval..

Comment: SetMaxInterval means :When  it will trigger some another application requeste for the location so  that time only MaxInterval trigger.

Comment: Thanks, I am creating Request with serInterval(1000) and setFastestInterval(500) and Priority PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY but still update is taking an average of 5sec. Also I am requesting location from Foreground Services, so It should provide update more quickly.

Comment: When you setInterval to 10sec and setFastestInterval to 5sec.Then the location update is called every 5sec.

Comment: Sure I will upvote for helpful answer, I am creating location request with 1 sec and fastInveral with 0.5 sec, but getting update in 5 sec

Comment: @d4h i already told bro..That means may be in you mobile some other applications like facebook (or)whatsapp(or)amazon etc. requesting for the locationServices...so you cannot get exact interval